# How can I call yandex navigator from my windows phone 8 app?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, yandex, yandex-maps

How can I call yandex navigator from my windows phone 8 app?? I want to call yandex navigation app from my app??

Answer (score 0):

from here: [Launch another app from wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496119/launch-another-app-from-wp7)

In Windows Phone 8 however you can use so called protocol handlers, so for example if you wan to launch Skype with selected user, you can use something like:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync("skype:myskypeid");
```

Comment: is there yandex naviagator dll for windows phone 8? I have current coordinate. I want to start yandex navigator from my wp8 app.

Comment: You can launch installed Yandex Navigator app. But i'm not sure that you can pass parameters/coordinates  to this app. About which dll are you asking?