# Sharing text content to whatsapp in windows phone 7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

This link below is a article for Windows phone 8

[Share content via whatsapp in wp8 apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146271/share-content-via-whatsapp-in-wp8-apps/21150972#21150972)

I would like to know if the same would work for a Windows phone 7 app or is there any other method to share content to whatsapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Simple Words "NOT POSSIBLE".

Technically, there is no way by which two independent apps could communicate with each other.
This feature is restricted in windows phone operating system right now.

The link posted in your question has one of the answers like:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("whatsapp:"));
```

But this is also not the idle solution as it would just launch the app whats app. Note that is isn't going to post the data from the app directly to whatsapp(that's what I wrote in the first line of my answer.) And this partial solution is also possible only in windows phone 8 as URI launchers are supported in  wp8 only

have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

And check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496119/launch-another-app-from-wp7) stack overflow post as well.